# SQLALCHEMY "EncryptedType" sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) data must be bytes-like

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, cryptography, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi I understand the problem I need to send 'bytes' data, I have looked at similar problems here and can see two easy solutions 1/ bytes(name, 'utf-8') or 2/ name.encode('utf-8') I have tried both of these and can see that I am sending a bytes object but I get the same error warning.

```
models.py
from sqlalchemy_utils import EncryptedType
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type import AesEngine
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class Clients(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    buyer = db.Column(EncryptedType(db.String(250), secret_key, AesEngine,'pkcs5'))
    name = db.Column(EncryptedType(db.String(250), secret_key, AesEngine,'pkcs5'))
    repeat_buyer = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    Address_1 = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    Address_2 = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

and the view

```
clients.py

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        csv_file = request.files['file']
        csv_file = TextIOWrapper(csv_file, encoding='utf-8')
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        next(csv_reader)
        for row in csv_reader:
            client = Clients.query.order_by(Clients.id.desc()).filter(Clients.id==row[0]).first()
            if not client:
                client = Clients(id=row[0])
            client.buyer=row[1].encode('utf-8')
            client.name=row[1].encode('utf-8')
            client.repeat_buyer=row[9]
            client.Address_1=row[6]
            client.Address_2=row[7]
            db.session.add(client)
            db.session.commit()
            return
            """<html>
                    <body>          
                        <h1>Upload BB Paypal Payments</h1>
                        <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
                        <input type=file name=file>
                        <input type=submit value=Upload>
                        </form>
                    </body>
                   </html>"""
```

I have a mysql database, I tried this same code with sqlite and it worked with no errors, I am using migrate to upgrade the db and when I added this new class I got an error "sqlalchemy_utils" not defined when I "flask db upgrade" so to over come this I manually added this line to the migrations version. I believe the error is the point the data is commited, sqlalchemy is not encoding the data as it is commited, but I dont understand why. on a simple one page app with sqlite it works, but on the full app with mysql it does not

this is the table:

```
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+---------------- 
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+---------------- 
| id           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment 
| buyer        | blob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                
| name         | blob    | YES  |     | NULL    |                
| repeat_buyer | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
| Address_1    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
| Address_2    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------
```

this is the data in the full error log

```
EDIT
[2021-07-24 16:05:50,036] ERROR in app: Exception on /dhqqdkxnnjfcnqnqqddj/clients/upload [POST]
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 35, in _check_byteslike, referer: https://erdm.fr/dhqqdkxnnjfcnqnqqddj/clients/upl$
memoryview(value), referer: 
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType', referer: 
referer: 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:, referer: 
Traceback (most recent call last):, 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1671, in _execute_context, 
 dialect, self, conn, execution_options, *args, **kw,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1077, in _init_compiled
for key in compiled_params, referer: 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 1077, in <dictcomp>, 
for key in compiled_params, referer: 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py", line 1374, in process, referer: 
return impl_processor(process_param(value, dialect)), referer:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/types/encrypted/encrypted_type.py", line 469, in process_bind_param, 

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 37, in _check_byteslike,
raise TypeError("{} must be bytes-like".format(name))
[SQL: INSERT INTO clients (id, buyer, name, repeat_buyer, `Address_1`, `Address_2`) VALUES (%(id)s, %(buyer)s, %(name)s, %(repeat_buyer)s, %(Address_1
[parameters: [{'Address_2': 1, 'buyer': b'john clease', 'name': b'The Old Parot', 'repeat_buyer': b'6', 'id': b'1', 'Address_1': 1}]], referer:
```

If you need any more code please ask, but the code here is almost enough to try it out which I did and it worked but not with mysql!
I got this code from [sqlalchemy EncryptedType](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/encrypted/encrypted_type.html#EncryptedType)

Environment details

- python3.7.2
- sqlalachemy 1.3.10
- SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.35.0
- cryptography==3.4.7
- mysql-connector-python==8.0.25
- PyMySQL==0.9.3

EDIT:
Following @snakecharmerb point I added the begining of the error code which show a first problem, I investigated this and found that no secret_key was being given, I found that my .env file was not being found with its secret key. a noob mistake, thanks for the help

Warm regards Paul

Comment: I still can't reproduce - here's my reproduction attempt, in case it's any use https://pastebin.com/z69b49Sw

Comment: I have created a copy that works with Mysql but I still can't get this code to work in my main app, here is the code https://pastebin.com/Ei33ek1F, I dont understand how this code works here but the exact same code will not work when I use migrate to update the database, My main app has been developing fo several years, and has about 20 tables so each time I change or add a new table I use "flask db migrate "name" to help modify the database, but with this encrypt code I got an error message.

Comment: hey @pascale, i have the same problem, using migrate to add a column as encryted leads me to the same error as "data must be bytes-like". Did you find something? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Sovanna, this problem was a little while ago and if I remember correctly the problem was the "secret key" not being found so that the data was not being correctly encoded, all worked ok with the trial code shown here but when I added this to my main code an error occured because I did not have my secret key set up correctly. try that, If that is not the problem contact me again and I will have a closer look. Warm regards Paul